# Deleting custom Object from Stack container in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, tree, stack

I have a standard tree node consisting of 3 pointers to an object of it's own type and character value. I am trying to convert that tree into a stack using the standard C++ stack container for parsing.

The following is a segment of code that works correctly.

```
 stack<Node*> temp;
 Node* trash;
...
 trash = temp.top();
 temp.pop();        
 delete(trash);
...
```

This performs what I need without any memory leaks; however, if I use just

```
 temp.pop();
```

It produces a memory leak in this spot. Why does it do this? Is this an issue with the default contructor? What would be needed to reduce it to the first option, if at all possible? Or is this the 'proper' way to do this?

Comment: If you want pop to delete the object,  use stack of smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing pointers in your stack. The first code example properly cleans up the memory that the pointer points to. The `pop` on its own does not do that. It simply removes the pointer itself from the stack.